# making it easy to change implementation of an interface later on

Tags: java, oop, interface

So in java the way to initialise an interface, such as a collection or list, is to create an instance of a class that implements it, eg:

```
Collection<Object> moo = new ArrayList();
```

If I wanted to specify an implementation at a later time in my code, I was thinking of doing this by creating another class like:

```
class ListList extends ArrayList{

}
```

and then initialise the variable with

```
Collection<Object> moo = new ListList();
```

And then all that's required if I want to change the implementation later on is to change what ListList extends.

So, here's the question.. is there a better way of doing this (I still feel as though I'm inexperienced with this type of thing).

Comment: Are you only going to override certain methods or something?

Comment: What kind of behaviours would ListList add to the class it extends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a better way of doing this

Yes: use a factory method:

```
public static Collection<Object> createCollection() {
    return new ArrayList<Object>(); // change this later, if need be
}
```

Then, invoke the factory rather than instantiating:

```
Collection<Object> moo = createCollection();
```

Your suggestion of using a "dummy" subclass might appear attractive, but such abuses of inheritance invariably lead to pain and suffering later on. You really don't want to do that.

Comment: Oh ok, so where would be a good place to put the factory method? In a separate class or in the same class that it gets used in?

Comment: @Liang: Whichever one you prefer. If it's just one method that's only used in one class, then just put it in that class. If you want to use it in several places, or if you have several factory methods, then a separate "factory class" is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it that way

```
Collection<Object> coll=new ArrayList(){
        //bla
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is a good one. Make your variable/field/... an instance of the interface and not of the concrete class you are using. This will force all your code to work against the interface (on the condition that you not start casting somewhere down your code path), and allows to replace the implementation later on with a different class if you feel the need for it.

One can start discussion about how you create that concrete class, like for example using a factory method as @skaffman suggested in his response. However, this might depend on the situation. If it is just for a one-time use like initializing a field you can just create the instance without bothering about factory methods.